# How to report fake Google Hangouts account

Tags: google-account, google-hangouts, phishing

Someone has created a fake Hangouts account using my son's first name and my last name.  Neither my son nor I have a Hangouts account.  My sister had gotten a message sent to her with a screenshot showing the account.  Is there a way of finding out who created it and how do I get rid of the fake account?

Answer (score 1):

You could try contacting Google's customer service department however it is unlikely that they will close the account, from their perspective it is very possible that someone in the world has that particular first and last name combination.

There would have to be some evidence that it is being used in a malicious manner towards you or your son, in which case you should report it to your local authorities who will be better able to assist in shutting down the account and investigating the source.